# Is there a better way to keep removing and reloading "unpacked" chrome extension when doing development

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a better way to keep removing and reloading "unpacked" chrome extension when doing development? I found myself doing this for a very long period of time already and start to think this doesn't feel like the "right way" to develop it. There must be a way it would automatically "compile" right?

Comment: No need to remove: just press the recycle icon on chrome://extensions page in the extension card. You can also use a hot-reload package for extensions (there are several probably) or you can add a hotkey via [commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) section and press it manually.

Comment: recycle icon? you meant the reload icon?

Comment: Did I confuse you? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following chrome extension to reload all unpacked chrome extensions during development, when pressing the extension icon in the topbar.
[Extensions Reloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid)

Additionally the options page for the extension provides a feature to reload the active tab, when pressing the extension icon.

Hope it helps.